# iterating over Redis hash keys with a wild card search

Tags: python, hash, redis, wildcard

I have redis keys and the values of those keys as hash set(key,value pairs).  I am using python to retreive the key values.
ex:

```
top_link:files
    key: file_path/foldername1
    value: filename1

    key: file_path/foldername2
    value: filename2

    key: test_path/foldername3
    value: filename3
```

I want to find out all hash set keys whose key name starts with "file_path"

I tried

```
all_keys = redis_connection.hscan_iter("top_link:files")
for key in all_keys:
  if key.startswith("file_path"):
    redis_connection.hget("top_link:files",key)
```

is there a better way to find all the hash keys that start with "file_path".  SCAN seems to do what i am trying to achieve.  But all the examples shows scan on top level keys (top_link:files) but not on hash keys.  Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide a `match` pattern in `hscan_iter` to get pairs of only matching keys. And by `hscan_iter`, you get key-value pairs as `tuple`s. So you don't have to use `hget` to get the values.

```
matched_pairs = redis_connection.hscan_iter('top_link:files', match='file_path*')
for keyvalue in matched_pairs:
  # Here `keyvalue` is a tuple containing key and value
  print keyvalue[0], keyvalue[1]
```

Output:

```
file_path/foldername2 filename2
file_path/foldername1 filename1
```

Comment: when i used hscan as below, it gives me a tuple with entire hash set. 
 but can you please show me how to fetch the matching keys?redis_connection.hscan("top_link:files", match="file_path*")